Cannot make rest position as pose position
I have an animation that starts with a weird pose. I want to insert a neutral/rest pose into frame 0. Based on several previous answers, I did the Alt-G, Alt-R, and Alt-S. I also have no bone constraint. It did reset the pose. But after I scrubbed the timeline back and forth, it went back to the old weird position. Is there anything else I should do. This is Blender 3.6. Thanks.



You did reset the pose - but did you save that with keyframes for all bones on frame 0? When the "weird pose" is keyframed on frame 0 (as you can see in the timeline), just resetting it will not change a lot, that is just temporary when keyframes exist. As soon as you move through the timeline, Blender will read the keyframed positions again. Are you familiar with keyframed animations?

Mixamo animations are baked. They have keyframes for every single frame. If you want to combine or mix poses & animations, have a look at the NLA editor.

I moved the entire animation about 15 frames to the right and inserted 2 new keyframes at position 0 and 10. So, those are baked too?

hello could you please share your file?

Sure. A couple more info. I did a retarget animation (using autorig) to a mixamo default t-pose model I downloaded (not a mixamo animation). Here's the google drive link. https://drive.google.com/file/d/1yl3pf1br58XXlt_hVuhCiZa-JkQIiWWz/view?usp=sharing

If I go to frame 0, reset the pose with Alt R, Alt S and Alt G, then press i to insert the keyframes, it works fine, so I'm not sure what's your problem?

So, after you insert a keyframe at frame 0, you're able to apply t-pose like my screenshot 2, and when you scrub left-right, the t-pose pose stays?

Yes look: https://zupimages.net/up/24/27/5kfu.gif

I guess I'm blind. Can you tell me what I missed from this video? The keyframe selections look a bit different than your capture. I played around a bit with that and nothing worked. I also updated my blender from 3.6.5 to the latest 3.6.13 last night. It didn't help either. https://imgur.com/a/ELjJh1g

do you press "i" once you've reset the pose? also are you sure that you have the correct keying setup (if you use the latest version of Blender)?

I knew it's something simple. Pressing "I" solved the issue. Thanks.

You have just forgotten to press i to insert the keyframes
